# How to Clear sessionStorage on User Logout

Tags: javascript, php

For some reasons I set sessionStorage to retrieve page State of scroll... But now each time I logout the sessionStorage doesn't clear even after I tried `sessionStorage.clear() or sessionStorage.removeItem(key)` please how can I unset this once the user logs out?

Comment: Can you give more context to this problem?

Comment: So maybe it's not sessionStorage but localStorage?

Comment: Not localStorage !!

Comment: I set a sessionStorage on index.php as User scrolls down the page I store page State to sessionStorage.. now refreshing the page auto scrolls back to where the user left off.. but the challenges am having is destroying the sessionStorage... Though doing ```sessionStorage.removeItem(key)``` on same page I set the session, it Clears it but I want to Clear this when the user logs out instead

Answer (score 1):

User Session Stored at Server side but sessionStorage is at client side script. add  at "you have successfully logged out" page

```
echo '<script> sessionStorage.removeItem("key")</script>';
```

Comment: I think that it would be more accurate to say that the `<script>` tag should belong on the *"you have successfully logged out"* page.  Alternatively, your client-side app could destroy its own SessionStorage key *before* issuing the logout call to the server.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Thank you for clarifying Artier's intent.  This answer helped me.